# Free/busy Query

Tags: python, timezone, google-calendar-api

Acording to documentation at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/freebusy/query to perform a freebusy query you must provide this parameters in the body:

```
{
  "timeMin": datetime,
  "timeMax": datetime,
  "timeZone": string,
  "groupExpansionMax": integer,
  "calendarExpansionMax": integer,
  "items": [
    {
      "id": string
    }
  ]
}
```

when building the query:

```
# calendarlist = a list with all the ids of the calendars I do query
# calendar is the access token to google calendar API
start = datetime.now()
end = start.replace(hour=23)
freebusy_query = {
        "timeMin": start,
        "timeMax": end,
        "timeZone": 'Europe/Madrid',
        "items": calendarlist
    }

availability = calendar.freebusy().query(body=freebusy_query).execute()
```

I get a response that tells me that:

```
TypeError: datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 14, 23, 00, 59, 999999)) is not JSON serializable
```

So I guess that my reading on the documentation is wrong and what I have to supply is a datetime string

Am I right?

How do I preserve the tzinfo when I transforming the datetime to a string?

```
date_format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%Z'
start_string = start.strftime(date_format)
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
start = datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0).isoformat() + "-04:00"
end = datetime.now().replace(hour=23, microsecond=0).isoformat() + "-04:00"



freebusy = service.freebusy().query(body=
    {"timeMin": start,
      "timeMax": end,
      "timeZone": 'Europe/Madrid',
      "items": calendarList
    }).execute()
```